# Python value testing 'abc' == True returns False

Tags: python, evaluation

I was writing a unit test to assert the return value is not empty, so I wrote something like `assert(value, True)` and I got an error `AssertionError: '72a7090610eb11e398d40050569e0016' != True`

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'abc' == True
False
```

I always thought that an non empty string or > 1 integers would evaluate to True, maybe I got confused with PHP.

And I always thought `if 'abc'`is equivalent to `if 'abc' == True` obviously I was wrong :(

Comment: Well you are comparing string with a boolean.

Comment: `non empty string or > 1 integers would evaluate to True`. "Evaluate to true" refers to it's boolean value as defined in the class's `__bool__`. You want `bool('abc') == True`, which will work the way you expect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are conflating thruthness with equality; they are not the same thing. Use `bool()` if you need to compare to actual `True` and `False` values:

```
>>> bool('abc')
True
```

You generally do *not* compare directly with `== True` or `== False`. Rather, you use conditional expressions or statements:

```
if 'abc':
    pass

while 'def':
    pass

foo if 'abc' else bar
```

Only empty containers, numeric zero and `False` and `None` are falsey, everything else is thruthy; you can use `bool()` to test for that condition explicitly. You can make custom types  look like empty containers by implementing [`__len__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) and returning `0`, or look like a number by implementing [`__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)<sup>*</sup> and returning `False` when the instance is to be the boolean equivalent of numeric zero.

<sup>*<sub>In Python 3, use [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) instead</sub></sup>.

Comment: As a side note, `__nonzero__()` is `__bool__()` in 3.x.

Comment: @Lattyware: Indeed, but the OP is using 2.7.

Comment: Indeed, just adding it as an additional bit of information, not a correction.

Comment: Yes I only found out this when I am writing unittest asserting the value is not empty.

Answer (score 7):

`'abc'` is not equal to `True`, but it's truthy. Those are two different concepts! in other words, this won't print `'ok'`:

```
if 'abc' == True:
    print 'ok'
```

... But this will:

```
if 'abc':
    print 'ok'
```

Comment: I should pay more attention to this, I come from a PHP world which has == and ===

Comment: @JamesLin `==` in PHP is Python's `==`, `===` is equivalent to Python's `is`, as far as I know, PHP has no equivalent to the Python 'truthiness' (`bool(...)`).

Comment: @Lattyware not exactly correct, `'abc' == true` in php condition will return True

Comment: @JamesLin Ah yes, I forgot how terrible PHP really is. `===` and `is` are not really the same at all.